# Maximum recursion level reached in django project

Tags: python

Browser Response

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.1.25/bigflow/Getprstatus/
Django Version:     2.0.3
Exception Type:     OverflowError
Exception Value:    

 Maximum recursion level reached

 Exception Location:    /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas      /io/json/json.py in write, line 99
Python Executable:  /var/www/bigb/venv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.5.2
```

Apache2 Hosted File

```
Alias /static /var/www/bigb/Bigflow/Bigflow/static
Alias /staticdemo /var/www/bigb/BigflowDemo/Bigflow/Bigflow/static

<Directory /var/www/bigb/Bigflow/Bigflow/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/bigb/BigflowDemo/Bigflow/Bigflow/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>



WSGIDaemonProcess bigflow processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/bigb/venv
WSGIProcessGroup bigflow
WSGIScriptAlias /bigflow /var/www/bigb/Bigflow/Bigflow/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess Bigflow_api processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/bigb/venv
WSGIProcessGroup Bigflow_api
WSGIScriptAlias /Bigflow_api /var/www/bigb/Bigflow_api/Bigflow_api/wsgi.py

WSGIDaemonProcess bigflowdemo processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} python-home=/var/www/bigb/venv
WSGIProcessGroup bigflowdemo
WSGIScriptAlias /bigflowdemo /var/www/bigb/BigflowDemo/Bigflow/Bigflow/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/bigb/Bigflow>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/bigb/BigflowDemo/Bigflow>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/bigb/Bigflow/Bigflow>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/bigb/Bigflow_api/Bigflow_api>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/bigb/BigflowDemo/Bigflow/Bigflow>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

I'm working with django  project, Recently i have hosted a new application in the apache2 server ,now apache2 is running with two application , both the django  project are  working fine. But frequently i get some error like "Maximum recursion level reached" and my application fails to work. please help me  to  find the problem.

Is this correct to point both the application  towards same virtual environment(venv)

Comment: Looks there some infinite recursion somewhere.

Comment: how to fix @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: by looking at the traceback, and looking for repetitive recursive patterns. Then you need to find out what is semantically wrong with the corresponding algorithm.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Apache nor Django actually.

Comment: please post the python code that you're trying to execute

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after i found this quick and dirty solution just increase the recursion limit in your python script:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

Default is 951, if it's not working then i guess you need to look at the traceback for repetitive patterns

I hope it will be helpful to someone!